# How to transfer data from SQLiteDataTable to a TextBox

Tags: c#, forms, sqlite

I'm trying to link data from my db (sqlite) to my textboxes, but I don't know exactly how...

Here's what i'm trying:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT PRECO_PRODUTO FROM INGREDIENTES WHERE NOME_PRODUTO='"+listProdutos.SelectedIndex+"'", con);
        adapter.Fill(populate);

        List<DataTable> precoIng = new List<DataTable>();
        precoIng.Add(populate.Tables[0]);            

        con.Close();

        tbPrecoProduto.Text = precoIng[0];  //error here
    }
```

I think I need a way to convert the SQLiteDataTable to a string? I'm new on db stuffs. [This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg27j.png) and [this is my form design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYy5H.png), if helps...

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'string'". And 
if I do  tbPrecoProduto.Text = Convert.ToString(precoIng[0]); it just prints "table" on my textbox

Comment: Shouldn't `NOME_PRODUTO` be a name? Because I assume that `listProdutos.SelectedIndex` is an integer, isn't it?

Comment: Yep.. I did "listProdutos.SelectedIndex" so the query could catch specifically the data related to the product selected by the user

Comment: But if `SelectedIndex` is an int, the query `"SELECT PRECO_PRODUTO FROM INGREDIENTES WHERE NOME_PRODUTO='"+listProdutos.SelectedIndex+"'"` shouldn't return any results. Instead you might want to use something like `listProdutos.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Comment: Yea, you are right. I was thinking on this when I was writing de DELETE query and I forgot about this detail haha. Working now :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if you're trying to set the text of the TextBox to a DataTable. This doesn't quite make sense, as the type `DataTable` isn't the same as a `string`. You'd first have to extract the data out of your table like that:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder ();
foreach (var rowObject in precoIng [0].Rows)
{
    var row = (DataRow) rowObject;
    var id    = row ["ID_PRODUTO"].ToString ();
    var name  = row ["NOME_PRODUTO"].ToString ();
    var price = row ["PRECO_PRODUTO"].ToString ();
    var count = row ["QNT_PRODUTO"].ToString ();

    builder.AppendLine ($"Id: {id}; Name: {name}; Price: {price}; Count: {count}");
}

tbPrecoProduto.Text = builder.ToString ();
```

You can of course shorten this if you only want for example the price:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder ();
foreach (var rowObject in precoIng [0].Rows)
{
    var row = (DataRow) rowObject;
    var price = row ["PRECO_PRODUTO"].ToString ();

    builder.AppendLine (price);
}

tbPrecoProduto.Text = builder.ToString ();
```

And, btw, `precoIng[0]` will always be the same as `populate.Tables[0]`.

Alternatively you could write an extension method like that:

```
public static string GetData (this DataTable table)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder ();
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            builder.Append (column.ColumnName).Append (": ").Append (row [column]).Append ("; ");

    return builder.ToString ();
}
```

And then call `precoIng[0].GetData()` to get the data as a string.

If you want to be able to filter the data to get printed, you could do something like this:

```
public static string GetData (this DataTable table, List <string> columns = null)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder ();
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        if (columns == null)
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                builder.Append (column.ColumnName).Append (": ").Append (row [column]).Append ("; ");
        else
            foreach (var column in columns)
                builder.Append (column).Append (": ").Append (row [column]).Append ("; ");

    return builder.ToString ();
}
```

I do however feel as if you don't want the data of your whole table as a string, but rather want the data to certain ids or something. To help you with this, however, I'd need more precise information.

---

Ok, so it seems as if what you actually want is something like this:

```
var preco = precoIng.FirstOrDefault ()?.Rows.Cast <DataRow> ().FirstOrDefault ()? ["PRECO_PRODUTO"]?.ToString () ?? "";
```

Comment: Lololol what a answer, thanks haha. Yea! Actually, my point is to move all information about the "NOME_PRODUTO" to my textboxes. Respectively, NOME_PRODUTO to the first textbox, PRECO_PRODUTO to the second one and the QNT_PRODUTO to the last one. I did the implementation of your second codeblock, but it returns nothing ( " " )... Can you help me with this? Maybe i'm still doing something wrong. Print( https://puu.sh/ApjXZ/83bcbb0a21.png )

Comment: @IgorHenriques could you give me the value of `precoIng [0].Rows.Count` and of `string.Join("; ", precoIng [0].Rows[0].ItemArray)`?

Comment: I'm aware of that - it's just weird that it contains anything at all. What is an example value of `listProdutos.SelectedIndex`?